# R, Ways to access matrix elements if missing data is expected

Tags: r, matrix

I'm coming from a Java/C++ background and just recently started using R for real projects.

One thing I constantly struggle with is matrix (or any type of list/vector/etc.) accession.

Often times I have a set of data stored in a matrix-object and want to extract a row, perform some calculations, and then move on to the next row. 
However, sometimes I can't just iterate through the matrix-rows but instead need to access them by row-name.

The problem arises, when there is no row of a given name (which tends to happen a lot in the data I'm dealing with). My function simply aborts.

What I'm desperately looking for is to access the matrix-row in a way, where I simply get a 'null'-, 'FALSE'-, whatever-Object, that enables me to continue running the script, even if data is missing. 
Sure I can check whether my given rowname is part of all matrix-rownames, but that's simply not feasible runtime-wise.

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve]! Edit your question to give a reproductable example!

Comment: *Sure I can check whether my given rowname is part of all matrix-rownames, but that's simply not feasible runtime-wise* I guess you have large data and probably using rownames instead of indices is not the best choice "runtime-wise"...

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example? You could convert your "character" indices in "integer" using constructs like `m[match(c("b", "d", "a", "b"), rownames(m)), ]` instead of `m[c("b", "d", "a", "b"), ]` (where `m = matrix(1:6, 3, 2, , list(letters[1:3], NULL))`) or, if you're trying to use a more specialized structure, add a method to the `"["` function and make appropriate checks inside.

Comment: To give a more specific example for my problem: 

Say I have data from an experiment, where the rownames are identifiers and the columns are values, where each column refers to measurements at a given time. 
Additionally, I have a list of pairs of identifiers. 
Now, I want to go through all pairs of identifiers, extract the two rows for each pairs and then test for correlation between these two rows. 
However, the data and the list of pairs come from different sources, there are identifiers in my list of pairs that won't match any identifiers in my data matrix and vice versa.

Comment: I know there are workarounds like filtering the data-matrix before, etc., I was just curious if there are other ways in R to access elements that would make things more convenient. 

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your statement into `try()` and then check if there was an error.

```
tmp <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2, dimnames = list(c("a","b"), c("c", "d")))
result <- try(tmp["x",])
if(inherits(result, "try-error")) result <- NA
```

see also the R help

```
?try
?tryCatch
```